MySQL docker container stuck reloading
My stack is win10/wsl2/ubuntu/docker desktop.
I'm stuck on running a MySQL docker container.
This is a part of my docker-compose.yml:
      mysql:
        hostname: a-mysql
        container_name: a-mysql
        image: mysql:8
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
            - ./mysql/dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        env_file:
            - .env
        ports:
            - 7306:3306
        environment:
            TZ: "Asia/Jerusalem"
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_INITDB_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_INITDB_USER_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_INITDB}
        networks:
            - external-php-net
            - internal-php-net
        command: ["mysqld", "--mysql-native-password=ON"]
        #command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

As well I have a Makefile:
up: #create and start containers
    @docker compose up -d

down: #stop containers
    @docker compose down

rebuild: #rebuild all
    @docker compose down && docker compose up -d --build

connect_back: #connect to laravel application
    @docker exec -it ]php-fpm bash

database-import:
    @../e.back/database/snapshots/database_import.sh

setup:  ## Create and start containers
    $(MAKE) up-redis
    $(MAKE) up-mysql
    $(MAKE) install
    $(MAKE) up-frontend
    $(MAKE) up-php
    #$(MAKE) init
    $(MAKE) up-nginx

So I come to the docker files containing folder using my ubuntu installation and run "make setup".
What happens - all of the containers are running (there're redis, php-fpm, admin, etc) - but MySQL is always rebooting.
The log I have for this situation:
2024-07-15 15:23:16 2024-07-15T12:23:16.324649Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-07-15 15:23:19 2024-07-15T12:23:19.486488Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-07-15 15:23:21 mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2024-07-15 15:23:21 2024-07-15T12:23:21.776189Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010735] [Server] Could not open the mysql.plugin table. Please perform the MySQL upgrade procedure.
2024-07-15 15:23:21 2024-07-15T12:23:21.776800Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2024-07-15 15:23:21 2024-07-15T12:23:21.777242Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2024-07-15 15:23:21 2024-07-15T12:23:21.951887Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2024-07-15 15:23:21 2024-07-15T12:23:21.952560Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2024-07-15 15:23:21 2024-07-15T12:23:21.952903Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2024-07-15 15:23:21 2024-07-15T12:23:21.953261Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2024-07-15 15:23:21 2024-07-15T12:23:21.953587Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2024-07-15 15:23:23 2024-07-15T12:23:23.546298Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2024-07-15 15:23:23 2024-07-15T12:23:23.690225Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2024-07-15 15:23:23 2024-07-15T12:23:23.805946Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013595] [Server] Failed to initialize TLS for channel: mysql_main. See below for the description of exact issue.
2024-07-15 15:23:23 2024-07-15T12:23:23.806030Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010069] [Server] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2024-07-15 15:23:24 mysqld: Cannot change permissions of the file 'private_key.pem.temp' (OS errno 1 - Operation not permitted)
2024-07-15 15:23:24 2024-07-15T12:23:24.850250Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010295] [Server] Could not set file permission for private_key.pem
2024-07-15 15:23:24 2024-07-15T12:23:24.850316Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-07-15 15:23:26 2024-07-15T12:23:26.457062Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.4.1)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-07-15 15:23:26 2024-07-15T12:23:26.457140Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.
2024-07-15 15:23:29 2024-07-15 15:23:29+03:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.4.1-1.el9 started.
2024-07-15 15:23:33 2024-07-15 15:23:33+03:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-07-15 15:23:33 2024-07-15 15:23:33+03:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.4.1-1.el9 started.
2024-07-15 15:23:34 '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2024-07-15 15:23:34 mysqld: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf' is ignored.
2024-07-15 15:23:35 2024-07-15T12:23:34.607950Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
2024-07-15 15:23:35 2024-07-15T12:23:35.265552Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.4.1) starting as process 1
2024-07-15 15:23:35 2024-07-15T12:23:35.329779Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2024-07-15 15:23:35 2024-07-15T12:23:35.381988Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000054] [Server] World-writable config file '/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf' is ignored.
2024-07-15 15:23:35 2024-07-15T12:23:35.398682Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010107] [Server] World-writable config file '/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf' has been removed.
2024-07-15 15:23:35 2024-07-15T12:23:35.400891Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010075] [Server] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 0e9d63d9-42a5-11ef-b1b9-0242ac130003.
2024-07-15 15:23:35 2024-07-15T12:23:35.533081Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.

I'd appreciate any help with this, as I've been stuck for almost 2 days already. Thank you!
Well. I see the permission issue, and I think I tried all possibilities to fix it - changed permissions with chmod, added the meta thing to wsl.cnf and so on and so forth.

If the problem is strictly around the database, do you have the same problem if you delete all of the other containers from the Compose setup, and just run docker compose up without the Make wrapper?  (Are you missing some dependencies in the Makefile; should up depend on docker-compose.yml, for example?)

I've also seen a couple of hints that things that are very strict about filesystem permissions might not run well with bind mounts on non-Linux hosts; for example Permissions error with docker compose on macOS recommends using a Docker named volume for database storage.  Is the ./mysql_data directory in the WSL filesystem space?

Why is this tagged with PHP and Laravel? Would that work different without these two?

Have you created a certificate for MySQL?

For anyone, who struggles that issue as well.
Here's how I made it work:

Simply navigate to your project folder, where the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml are located. Do that via your VSCode terminal, cmd or something NOT related to WSL + ubuntu and run 'docker compose up'.
NO WSL NO UBUNTU, that's important.

That would somehow initialize your container with the correct permissions on Windows. You'll find that the container did run and all the permissions are set correctly.

Go to your WSL and do the docker compose down
From the WSL do the docker compose up.

That worked for me. Good luck!

The issue seems related to permission errors and the initialization of MySQL.
Ensure that the files and directories mounted to the MySQL container have the correct permissions. Use chmod to set the appropriate permissions. For example:
chmod -R 755 ./mysql_data
chmod -R 644 ./mysql/my.cnf
chmod -R 755 ./mysql/dump

The error log mentions World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf' is ignored. Ensure your config file does not have world-writable permissions:
chmod 644 ./mysql/my.cnf

Also Ensure that the WSL2 filesystem metadata is properly enabled. Add the following to your /etc/wsl.conf in your WSL2 instance:
[automount]
options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"

Restart your WSL2 instance after making these changes
wsl --shutdown


Hey, brother! That's amazing answer and I hope, that it would help someone, but me. Anyway, that's all the best I could find in other topic related questions here.
